# I want to create linked list in Python but classes which I created do not interact with each other

Tags: python, linked-list

Here is my code:

```
class Node: 
    data = None
    next_node = None

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node data: %s>"%self.data


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None
    
    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0

        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next_node

        return count
```

You can see that in line 27 next_node does not light up. I guess problem is next_node from class Node can not go to class LinkedList, but I do not know why.

When I am trying to get size of list which contains 1 number - I have in output this:
`bound method LinkedList.size of <__main__.LinkedList object at 0x0000020177C76B10` instead of 1.

Comment: Apparently you're not _calling_ the method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have defined `next_node` as an attribute of the Node class but you are trying to access it as an attribute of the LinkedList class.

You need to create Node objects and link them together using the `next_node` attribute. Something like this should work for you:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node data: %s>" % self.data


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None
    
    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0

        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next_node

        return count

    def add(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next_node = self.head
        self.head = new_node

# example
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.add(1)
print(my_list.size()) #outputs 1
```